# Rspec testing create and redirect with factories and subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, dry

I want to keep my tests as DRY as possible, thus, they look like this:

```
describe "creating new product" do
    subject { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }

    it "should increase product count by one" do
        expect{ subject }.to change{ Product.count }.by(1)
    end

    it "and then redirect to product's page" do
        expect(subject).to redirect_to(product_path)
    end
end
```

This is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :product do
      sequence(:title) { |n| "Book#{n}" } 
      description "Some crazy wibbles, they are fun"
      image_url "freddie_mercury.jpg"
      price 56.99
   end  
end
```

This is my model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image'
  }
end
```

From time to time my first test pass (when I change the name within factory), but after a while I get:

```
ProductsController creating new product should increase product count by one
 Failure/Error: subject { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Title has already been taken
```

which is kinda crazy, because I defined the sequence (I tried with do...end blocks, other than 'n' variables - I know it's a bit silly, but nevertheless)

Then, the second test fails as well:

```
ProductsController creating new product and then redirect to product's page
 Failure/Error: expect(subject).to redirect_to(product_path)
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

There I just don't know anymore what to try. Some of my attempts:

```
expect(subject).to redirect_to(product_path(assign(:product))
expect(subject).to redirect_to(product_path(assign(:product).id)
expect{ subject }.to redirect_to(product_path(assign(:product))
expect(subject).to redirect_to(product_path(subject))
expect(subject).to redirect_to(product_path(subject.id)
expect(subject).to redirect_to(product_path(response)
expect(response).to redirect_to(product_path(assign(:product))
```

I would appreciate any feedback, thanks in advance!

P.S. 
This is rails_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Comment: can you should us what your rails_helper.rb looks like? specifically I'm looking to see if your database setup is what's causing your problems.

Comment: Sure, I didn't touch it though. Here we go:

Edit: in comments markup is hard to read, added rails_helper.rb at the end of my initial post.

Comment: I stumbled upon some different code, that, however solves my problem:

`describe "creating new product" do
  before :each do
         @product = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product)
       end

       it "increases Product count number by one" do
        expect{ post :create, product: @product }.to change(Product, :count).by(1)
       end

     it "redirects to the created product's page" do
         expect(post :create, product: @product).to redirect_to product_path(assigns(:product))
       end
    end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP posted the answer in a comment, so I'm just moving it here.

```rb
    describe "creating new product" do
      before :each do           
        @product = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product)         
      end           
    
      it "increases Product count number by one" do
        expect(post :create, product: @product).to change(Product,:count).by(1)
        end
    
      it "redirects to the created product's page" do
        expect(post :create, product: @product).to redirect_to product_path(assigns(:product))
      end
    end
```